# last day of month in impala

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

is the a better/ shorter solution to

```
select
add_months (date_sub(trunc (to_timestamp(cast (dim_evt_dte_key as string), "yyyyMMdd"), 'month'), 1), 1) as end_month
from old;
```

to  get the last day of each month?? IS THERE AN END OF MONTH FUNCTION? EOMONTH seems not to work in impala
 to make things complex: `dim_evt_dte` is BIGINT: 20170210

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below using `last_day()` function

```
select last_day(to_timestamp(cast (dim_evt_dte_key as string), "yyyyMMdd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method in Impala is to use `trunc()` or `date_trunc()`:

```
select (trunc(dim_evt_dte_key, 'MMM') + interval 1 month) - interval 1 day) as end_month
from old;
```

This assumes that the key is a timestamp.